# SmartGWT: horizontally center an HTMLFlow

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I got an VLayout which occupies 100% of width on the screen.

It contains some HTMLFlow elements, they all are centered. There is one Flow that has the same width as the screen and I want to "split" it in 2

e.g. from

```
                            "Time remaining: 01:01:01"
```

to

```
                               "Time remaining: 
                                   01:01:01"
```

So, I tried setting the flow width to 50%, which controls my HTMLFlow length perfectly, but then the align moves to the left,

```
"Time remaining: 
01:01:01"
```

then I tried to include it inside an HLayout so it remains centered but the width gets override and is not 50% width but less.

```
                                    "Time 
                                  remaining: 
                                   01:01:01"
```

How I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add `<br />`s to the HTML-string. There is no way to control linewrapping in SmartGWT's HTMLFlow itself.

From HTMLFlow's JavaDoc:

`Use the HTMLFlow component to display HTML content that should expand to its natural size without scrolling. [..] NOTE: Since the size of an HTMLFlow component is determined by its HTML contents, this component will draw at varying sizes if given content of varying size.`

Comment: I wish I could just br, is not like that line has exactly 4 words, is dynamic content.

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful as well. Since the HTMLFlow size is given by its content, I thought that making a 50% width box contain the HTMLFlow could help, the problem with that is the container getting stuck on the left